# Connecting Bike Controls to a Game Simulation

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, htc-vive

Am building a simple VR game. An infinite runner - the complexity is however to receive the inputs. There are three inputs:
1) Acceleration
2) Gear / Clutch
3) Break 
4) Direction (left / right)

I want to tie this up with my Yamaha Fazer Bike. So When I sit on my bike and with the Oculus / HTC Vive - I can go for a virtual ride and control the game as though am really driving the bike. So I need to connect the bike's hardware with my Oculus Game.

Is there any way to do so. Do we have any game controllers  that can be purchased for this simulation ?

Answer (score 1):

When you build your VR game you are just inputs like any other normal non-VR game so the question isn't directly a VR question, but rather how to get the bike input into the game.

If you are using a Game Engine they have ways to map in input from controllers or other forms of input.

With a bike you would need a sensor to let the game know that you are moving and/or turning.

My best bet would to use a magnet on the wheel that same way pedometer on bikes work

For the rest you will need some sensor and program it to the movement... this can become a very huge hobby type project and you would really need quite the space to fully rig this bike in a stationary setting